# Invalid value for Sub layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I am getting exactly [this error](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0047000001rr000000) when trying to add locations to a service area within ModelBuilder.  However, the symptoms mentioned in that link relate to my tool being called from a differing language, and mines the standard US install.

I have the iterator pulling a table in (with a date field) and pushing it to a 'time of day' parameter for the Make Service Area.  I think thats all setup fine.  Just not sure why its having issues with adding facilities (facility is one point from a featureclass) and when adding the previous layer to the display, I can see there is a sublayer called Facilities.

[image]

- If I remove the Iterator, it works.
- With the iterate field values, it works if I don't use an inline variable for changing the output layer name in make service area to *Service Area%i%* (i.e it overwrites the output every time).

Not too sure where to go from here.

Can anyone provide me with some tips on how to get this working?

Comment: The help file suggests "expos[ing] the sub_layer parameter of the Add Locations tool as a model parameter." Did you try that? What happened?

Comment: I did try that and it gives me option to choose facilities when running tool and same error